# set style to first column excel

Tags: c#, excel

How can we set style to all cells in first column in excel? For instance:

```
    Excel.Range rangeRows;
    rangeRows = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("a1","a174");
    rangeRows.Font.Bold = true;
```

What would be better to set style to whole column?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I would seriously consider looking at [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com) if you have to do anything programatically with Excel.

It supports a number of different ways to create Ranges (by Alphanumeric ID or Index etc...)

e.g.

```
var newFile = new FileInfo(outputDir.FullName + @"\sample6.xlsx");

var pck = new ExcelPackage(newFile);

var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Content");

ws.Cells["A:B"].Style.Font.Bold = true; //Sets font-bold to true for column A & B
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice ... By the way can you recommend a beneficial ebook pdf for wpf and mvvm?